# Beamer columns misaligned vertically

Tags: beamer, table-of-contents, vertical-alignment, columns

I'm trying to pu my beamer TOC on two columns and I have this problem.
When I divide my page in two equal columns, the left column is vertically misaligned.

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
\frametitle{Le Langage}
\begin{columns}[t]%
\begin{column}{.45\linewidth}%
\tableofcontents[part=1,sections=<1-2>]%
\end{column}%
\begin{column}{.45\linewidth}%
\tableofcontents[part=1,sections=<3-4>]%
\end{column}%
\end{columns}%
\end{frame}
```

[image]

But when I give a wider column at left, (When there is no line return) the columns are vertically aligned as I want.

```
\begin{frame}[plain]
\frametitle{Le Langage}
\begin{columns}[t]%
\begin{column}{.4\linewidth}%
\tableofcontents[part=1,sections=<1-2>]%
\end{column}%
\begin{column}{.6\linewidth}%
\tableofcontents[part=1,sections=<3-4>]%
\end{column}%
\end{columns}%
\end{frame}
```

[image]

**Do you know how to give my columns the same width and the correct vertical alignment ?**

Comment: Try giving the option `[T]` instead of `[t]` to `{columns}`.

Comment: It's working well with option `[T]`

Comment: @HerrK. Would you like to write up an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I cannot reproduce the problem without an MWE. But it seems that giving the option `[T]` instead of `[t]` to the `{columns}` environment would solve the problem.